# Streaming microphone access in NativeScript using Angular to listen for specific audio event

Tags: angular, audio, nativescript, microphone

I'm attempting to make an application in NativeScript that will be partially hands-free. The app is designed to be used while the user is biking, and the general idea is that an audio event (ideally the ring of the bicycle bell, less ideally speech) will trigger a pin to be dropped on the map. I can't seem to find a way to have perpetual access to the microphone in NativeScript to listen for either of these events.

I've spent the last couple days trying various NativeScript plug-ins like nativescript-speech-recognition, but as far as I can tell there aren't any options that maintain a perpetual microphone stream. I've found a few that record audio, but that's unnecessary for what I'm hoping to accomplish. I'm trying to avoid making the user press any sort of button because that will defeat the intention of the app. This is my first NativeScript app, so I'm not totally versed in what is and is not possible.

Comment: You will have to write a service and record audio form the service, so it can work in background.

Comment: @peterdolannola I realize your post is from a couple years ago, but I'm investigating something similar.  Did you ever find an approach that worked for you?